# Need to add column which contains "string" if any of the values in a certain column from another table contain that same "string"

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to modify a query to add a column whos value must be "fail" if any of the values with the same id from another table has "fail" in a certain column.

There are 3 tables, table 1 contains 4 rows(categories) of financial data(fixed income, equities, ratings, listings) with their systemId.

Table 2 contains over 1000 rows of financial data which may fall under any of those 4 categories. Table 2 also has a row called **STATUS** which may contain a value of: "running","fail", or "standby".

Table 3 holds general information about the data sets and has both the value of **id** and **systemId**.

I want to add a column to TABLE1(categories) called STATE which contains "fail" or "standy" if any of the rows with the the same systemId contains the value "fail" or "standby" ,and only show "running" if all rows with the same **systemId** (table2) have "running" in their status column on (table2).

---

TABLE 1

```
         category             systemId      ???STATE??? 

         fixed income         1                 ?
         listings             2                 ?
         ratings              3                 ?
         equities             4                 ?
```

TABLE 2

```
  ID                    STATUS

  45421158              failed 
  2121158              running  
  9464548888             running
  454548888             standby
  9948158              running
  78748158              running
```

TABLE3

```
  id                    **systemId**
  45421158              1
  98721158              1
  454548888             2
  6888888             2
  78748158              3
  9978158              3
```

---

I have tried so many different joins and sub queries and have had no luck. I am a UI dev and dont have access to the database only a sample which runs on java through the cache so I cant add new tables or anyting like that, it has to be 1 query so I can modiy the resource.

Thanks in advance you will be legit saving ma life!

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag would help.

Comment: "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.  Please tell us which _version_ of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am new to this. I have made edits if you wouldnt mind having a look. @tim

Comment: So for `category =  fixed income` what would be the value of STATE and why?

Comment: category = fixed income  | state = FAILED if any single row from table 2 has a failed status then the whole category is considered to be in a FAILED STATE @forpas

Comment: This explanation and more must be edited in your question.

Comment: @forpas Thanks, is it clearer now?

Comment: I think so. Try my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell what the columns in your table are.  But for the logic that you want, one method uses `CASE` and `EXISTS`.

The query looks like this, although I am not sure what the correlation conditions are exactly (that is, what matches the rows in the two tables):

```
select c.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from servicemetric.servicemetric m
                          where m.category = c.category and
                                m.status = 'fail'
             then 'fail'
             when exists (select 1
                          from servicemetric.servicemetric m
                          where m.category = c.category and
                                m.status = 'standby'
             then 'standby'
             else 'running'
        end) as imputed_status
from node.categories c;
```

You can also implement the logic using conditional aggregation:

```
select m.category,
       (case when sum(case when m.status = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'fail'
             when sum(case when m.status = 'standby' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'standby'
             else 'running'
        end) as status
from servicemetric.servicemetric m
group by m.category;
```

Or even using `coalesce()`:

```
select m.category,
       coalesce(max(case when m.status = 'fail' then status end),
                max(case when m.status = 'standby' then status end),
                max(m.status)
               )
from servicemetric.servicemetric m
group by m.category;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your input. I want to add that status is not a column in the categories table so the query must also create that column.

Comment: in the first case what did you mean by SELECT 1?

Comment: @rkras . . . `EXISTS` checks for the existence of a row.  It doesn't matter what values are on the row.  I use `1` because that is the easiest thing to type.

Comment: I only now see how poor my initial question was, if you dont mind having another look I have basically edited all over again and it is now closer to representing my issue. Thanks a million!!! @gordon

Answer (score 0):

You must join the 3 tables and `group by` category and systemid:

```
select
  t1.category,
  t1.systemid,
  case
    when sum(case when t2.status = 'failed' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'failed'
    when sum(case when t2.status = 'standby' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'standby'
    when sum(case when t2.status = 'running' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'running'
  end status
from table1 t1
left join table3 t3 on t3.systemid = t1.systemid
left join table2 t2 on t2.id = t3.id
group by t1.category, t1.systemid
```

I used `left` joins in case there are system ids missing from `table3`. If this is not the case change to `inner` joins

Comment: I tried your solution which makes sense however when it returns the data the STATE field is Null

Comment: In case it wasnt clear, in table 2 the status may be running for some rows and failing for others even though they are in the same category(systemId), however if even only 1 rows status is failed and the rest are running, the state of that category in table 1 must be failed.

Comment: This is why the code checks first for 'failed'. If there is 1 'failed' then status will be 'failed'. For the nulls you get this means that the join does not match any 'failed' or 'standby' or 'running'. Why? Is this your actual data?

Comment: i have checked and the data certainly matches the aforementioned values. I think the issue is that it is not cross referencing the system id when doing the checks if status is failed it is not grouping by systemid

Comment: The only way to check the code is if you create a fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4 with sample data.